# Java Swing Scrolling By Dragging the Mouse

Tags: java, swing, scroll, mouse, jscrollpane

I am trying to create a hand scroller that will scroll as you drag your mouse across a JPanel. So far I cannot get the view to change. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class HandScroller extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HandScroller();
    }

    public HandScroller() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        final JPanel background = new JPanel();
        background.add(new JLabel("Hand"));
        background.add(new JLabel("Scroller"));
        background.add(new JLabel("Test"));
        background.add(new JLabel("Click"));
        background.add(new JLabel("To"));
        background.add(new JLabel("Scroll"));

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(background);

        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JViewport viewPort = scrollPane.getViewport();
                Point vpp = viewPort.getViewPosition();
                vpp.translate(10, 10);
                background.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vpp, viewPort.getSize()));
            }
        };

        scrollPane.getViewport().addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        scrollPane.getViewport().addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);

        setContentPane(scrollPane);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I would think that this would move the view by 10 in the x and y directions, but it is not doing anything at all. Is there something more that I should be doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work. Simply, there is nothing to scroll, as the window is large enough (actually, `pack()` has caused the JFrame to resize [to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29))

Remove `pack();` and replace that line with, say, `setSize(60,100);` to see the effect.

Comment: Or call  `setPreferredSize(...);` as suggested in another answer: it depends on what is logically getting "downsized" in your application, either the window or the single UI component.

Answer (score 3):

I think so you can move the view in all directions with this code

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

           JViewport viewPort = scroll.getViewport();
           Point vpp = viewPort.getViewPosition();
           vpp.translate(mouseStartX-e.getX(), mouseStartY-e.getY());
           scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vpp, viewPort.getSize()));

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    mouseStartX = e.getX();
    mouseStartY = e.getY();

}
```

Comment: I got this to work by adding the two last lines to the `mouseDragged` function. It works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I added declarations of mouseStartX/Y as well as code to reset those values at the end of mouseDragged() so that mouse movements aren't multiplied from the position of the first mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

It is working. However, when you run this code, the `JScrollPane` is made large enough to fit all your items. Add (for instance)

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
```

and you'll see that your mouse events work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it is working correctly when I set the Preferred Size.